# Discord js bot is spamming message when user is streaming

Tags: javascript, discord, bots, streaming, status

I have a problem with my bot, my brother is a streamer and has a discord server
I want my to sends a message when my brother is streaming on Twitch

```
bot.on("presenceUpdate", (oldPresence, newPresence) => {
  if (newPresence.user.id === "BROTHER ID") {
    if (newPresence.guild.id === "GUILD ID") {
      if (newPresence.activities) {
        newPresence.activities.forEach(activity => {
          if (activity.type == "STREAMING") {
            bot.channels.cache.get("TWITCH CHANNEL ID").send(`@everyone **BrotherUsername** is streaming:\n${activity.url}`)
          }
        })
      }
    }
  }
});
```

The code works, the bot sends the message when my brother is streaming,
but it keeps spamming the message mutiple times.
Can someone help me please ? Thanks.